# How to set up beamer to grey out past items but hide future items?

Tags: beamer, itemize, highlighting, transparency

I know about `beamer`'s  feature `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` and `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` to hide or grey out *upcoming* `item`'s . But is there some way to have past items greyed (transparent) and future items hidden (invisible), so that only the current item is black/highlighted? And the best would be if on or 1 slide after the last all the `item`'s could be visible highlighted. Something like this:

- [grey] past 1
- [grey] past 2
- **current**
- [hidden] future 1
- [hidden] future 2
- [hidden] future 3

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From the [beamer manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section 17.6 (Transparency Effects), use `\setbeamercovered` to set the default cover behavior, and override it for old items with the `again covered` option.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{%
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item Apple
\item Peach
\item Plum
\item Orange
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]