# How to grey out previous items and hide future Items?

Tags: beamer

I m using [AAUsidebar theme](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/53cacfa98ec552d634beea5a/). Is there any way to get the effect asked in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288038/how-to-set-up-beamer-to-grey-out-past-items-but-hide-future-items) to this AAUsidebar theme.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You do it exactly the same way as in the answer you linked:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AAUsidebar}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamercovered{%
  again covered={\opaqueness<1->{15}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+>]
\item Apple
\item Peach
\item Plum
\item Orange
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]