# Beamer: Highlight current item in list

Tags: beamer, itemize, animations

I'm using `beamer` for a presentation. There's an `itemize` environment on a slide. For this (and possible more) `itemize`, I want the following behaviour:

- highlight the item I'm talking about (e.g., bold)
- gray out the items I talked about already (e.g., by `{\color{gray} old item}`
- items I'm going to talk about later are not visible yet
- no code duplication (e.g., writing sentences twice)

What I startet with was

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item<+> My first point
    \item<+> My second point
    \item<+> My third point
    \item<+> And my last point
\end{itemize}
```

I tried to get this done by user-defined commands like

```
\newcommand{\grayout}[1]{
    \item<+> #1
    \item<+-> {\color{gray} #1}
}
\begin{itemize}
    \grayout{My first item}
    ...
\end{itemize}
```

But this is not working well. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you aware of the `\alert` command?

Comment: Does this answer help you? [How to set up beamer to grey out past items but hide future items?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288050/134144)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> - highlight the item I'm talking about (e.g., bold)

can be done by using `\item<alert@+>` or automatically with `\begin{itemize}[<alert@+>]`

> - items I'm going to talk about later are not visible yet

`\begin{itemize}[<+->]`

> - gray out the items I talked about already (e.g., by {\color{gray} old item}

This is more tricky. Normally this would need something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288050/36296, but as your items are not visible before they are highlighted, you could simply change the colour to gray.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

{
    \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=gray}
    \begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
        \item My first point
        \item My second point
        \item My third point
        \item And my last point
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Green You're welcome! Your pink icon is a nice contrast to your green name :)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=50}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
    \item My first point
    \item My second point
    \item My third point
    \item And my last point
\end{itemize}   
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This comes close to my thoughts, but the future elements are already visible. However, nice solution.