# beamer how to dim out a past figure but hide a future textbox?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have a figure and a textbox in one of my slides. My goal is to implement a functionality where, upon the first click, the figure is displayed, and upon the next click, the figure fades out while the text box appears on top of the figure. I have attempted various solutions, but none have produced the desired outcome. For example, the following solution compiles without errors, but it does not yield the desired results

```
\only<1>{
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth{figures/_Q1.pdf}
}

\only<2>{
\uncover<1>{
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/_Q1.pdf}
\end{figure}
}

\uncover<1,2>{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[anchor=center, rectangle, draw=black, line width=0.5pt, fill=gray!15, align=center, text width=\textwidth, minimum height=3cm] at ([shift={(0cm,0cm)}]current page.center) (box) {
    \textit{TEXT GOES HERE.}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
}   
}
```

I have tried the solution from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288038/how-to-set-up-beamer-to-grey-out-past-items-but-hide-future-items#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20comment-,1%20Answer,-Sorted%20by%3A) but it didn't work:

```
\begin{itemize}[<+>]
    \item \begin{figure} \centering \includegraphics[width=\textwidth{figures/_Q1.pdf}\end{figure}
    \item \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[anchor=center, rectangle, draw=black, line width=0.5pt, fill=gray!15, align=center, text width=\textwidth, minimum height=3cm] at ([shift={(0cm,0cm)}]current page.center) (box) {
    \textit{This is the conclusion.}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}
```

I am encountering errors when compiling this code.

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
PS: I am using the Beamer Template found [here](https://github.com/pmichaillat/latex-presentation).

Comment: Please always post a compilable test document, not just code fragments.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Your question still does not contain a document which we can simply copy and paste to reproduce your problem. We still can't see if you load the  necessary packages. We still don't know what the ominous "errors" are you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-duck}};
  \fill<2->[black,opacity=0.6] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
  \node<2->[fill=lightgray] at (current bounding box.center) {Some Text};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!